# Oracle utl_smtp not working as expected with multipart/alternative content type

Tags: oracle, plsql, smtp

I would like to use the following [example](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11%3a%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1739411218448) by Ask Tom, but it does not work as expected. When I call it with

```
declare
begin
xxpay_smtp.html_email
(
   p_to            => 'to@email.com',      -- in varchar2,
   p_from          => 'from@email.com',   -- in varchar2,
   p_subject       => 'Subject FD',                    -- in varchar2,
   p_text          => 'Body FD',                       -- in varchar2 default null,
   p_html          => '<html>
    <head>
        <title>some subject</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Your <b>Html</b> email message here.
    </body>
</html>',                     -- in varchar2 default null,
   p_smtp_hostname => 'smtp.com',       -- in varchar2,
   p_smtp_portnum  => '25'                             -- in varchar2
);       
end;
```

It comes back with an email body that looks like this:

```
Body FD

--a1b2c3d4e3f2g1
content-type: text/html;

<html>
    <head>
        <title>some subject</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Your <b>Html</b> email message here.
    </body>
</html>
--a1b2c3d4e3f2g1--
```

I am using Outlook 2010. Does anyone know where the Ask Tom example goes wrong, or what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Looks fine to me. What were you expecting?

Comment: For the boundary "--a1b2c3d4e3f2g1" not to be displayed. For the content-type: text/html; not to be displayed. Only text or html to be displayed based on what the default setting of the mail client is.

Comment: Do you send the multipart header? i.e. `Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="a1b2c3d4e3f2g1"` should be sent prior to the message body.

Comment: Yes, the Ask Tom example does that.

Comment: You'll need to provide more details. e.g. can you get the raw data that is being sent to UTL_SMTP, or post the PL/SQL you're using?

Comment: I'm using the PLSQL from the Ask Tom article, along with the above. There's a link to the article in the first line.

Comment: Ok, I didn't want to make the assumption that you copied that code line-for-line. Anyway, I suspect the problem may be here: `l_temp := l_temp || 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=' || chr(34) || l_boundary ||  chr(34) || chr(13) || chr(10);` I think it needs an extra CR/LF to have a blank line before the first content boundary: `l_temp := l_temp || 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=' || chr(34) || l_boundary ||  chr(34) || chr(13) || chr(10) || chr(13) || chr(10);`

Comment: Thanks, looks like that worked. You can add it as an answer if you want the kudos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be an extra blank line after the headers, i.e. after the "Content-Type" line.

```
l_temp := l_temp || 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=' || 
                     chr(34) || l_boundary ||  chr(34) || chr(13) || 
                     chr(10);
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
l_temp := l_temp || 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=' || 
                     chr(34) || l_boundary ||  chr(34) || chr(13) || 
                     chr(10) || chr(13) || chr(10);
```